# Variational formulation how to find it

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, calculus-of-variations, reflexive-space

I have this problem
$$ - \operatorname{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) =f(u), x\in \Omega $$

With $\Omega $ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega $ the condition on $f$ is $f\in W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$ which is the dual of $ W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

My problem is to get the variational formulation  what is the primitive  of $f$?

Do I write$$ I(u)= \frac{1}{p} ||\nabla u||^p -\int F(u) dx$$ where $ F(t)= \displaystyle{\int_0^t f(s) ds}$?

Comment: The functional should be of the form $$I(u) = \int_{\Omega} [(\text{term that yields p Laplacian} - F(u)] dx$$ where $F(u) = \int f(u) du = \int_{0}^{u} f(s) ds$.

Comment: So as i write it ! And can we say that  F is bounded i mean is it right to write $|F(u)| \leq  ||f|| ||u||$ ? @MatthewCassell

Comment: I don’t think your problem makes sense. Should it be $f(x)$ and $x\in \Omega$? If $u\in\Omega$, then $ u$ would be a vector, while $f$ takes value in the real.

Comment: f is in W^{-1,p'}

Comment: Seems right but could say that $F'(u) = f(u)$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

Comment: A function $f\in W^{-1,p’}$ is a linear continuous function $f:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$, so $ f( u)$ is a real number. On the other hand, if $u$ is in $\Omega$, then $ u$ is a vector, so it’s gradient is a matrix, and so it’s divergence is a matrix. You are saying that a matrix equals a real number

Comment: @Gio67 sorry $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $x\in \Omega$

Answer (score -1):

The functional is given by

$$I(u) = \frac1p \|u\|_{W^{1,p}_0}^p - \int_{\Omega} F(u(x)) dx$$

where $F(t) = \int_0^t f(s)ds$.

See [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/PM/58f3/pm58f304.pdf) by Dinca, Jebelean, and Mawhin. The formula is on page 356 and the preceding discussion is its derivation.

Comment: If you read that paper, they have $f(x,u)$, where $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, so if you remove the $x$ variable, you are left with a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, so at best you could assume $f\in W^{-1,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and not $(\Omega)$

Comment: The way I'm reading the question the assumption is $f(u(x))\in W^{-1,p'}(\Omega)$. If $f$ has inputs in $\Omega$, what does $f(u)$ mean? In my reading the setting is the same with the paper, just a simpler case where $f$ only depends on $u$, not $x$. @Vrouvrou please clarify this point.

Comment: The assumption  is f in the dual space, I dont know if f(u) has a sens but this is what i have